# Servers and normal PC

Tags: nameserver

I have a Server 2008 computer, with a domain running, I am trying to run my domain on my WIN7 computer too.

I have entered the nslookup in RUN, and then typed in my domain name on my WIN7 Ultimate computer, but it came back as an Non-authoritive Answer

Comment: What are you trying to ask?

Comment: I am trying to ask for help on my problem please. Sorry forgot to mention it.

Comment: Whats your problem?

Comment: My windows 7 computer doesn't want to add the existing domain, and it keeps on saying "An Active Domain Directory Controller for the domain could not be contacted. How can I connect to the domain?

Comment: "run my domain on my WIN7" makes no sense are you trying to join your wind7 to your domain, or do you simply mean a dns "domain" and its not working as a resolver?

Comment: you need to configure your win7 dns to point to your domain controller for dns resolution.

Comment: how do i configure my dns to point at the domain?
and i mean im trying to join the win7 to the domain

Answer (score 1):

Configure the DNS client settings on the Windows 7 computer to use the DNS server that is supporting your AD domain (presumably it's the same server that is the DC for the domain).

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: Wow. OK. In the TCP/IP properties of the NIC on the Windows 7 computer configure the DNS server setting with the ip address of the DNS server that is supporting your AD domain, which is presumably the same server that is the DC for the domain.

Comment: I have no idea where to check the DC etc... So how will i know what the ip address of the DC is?

Comment: @Andre This is a site for professional systems administrators. If you're truly a professional, your company needs to send you to some basic training. If you're not a professional, you're asking on the wrong site.

Comment: @MDMarra I am sorry, I allowed ask questions, aren't I? And NO WHERE it says that this site is for professionals. I am just trying to find out stuff. my Company lost its Networking manager and I was immediately put in this job, to assist basic networking problems till the company can hire a new manager. So im SORRY for asking a couple of questions to help me do my JOB!

Comment: `"And NO WHERE it says that this site is for professionals."` - Actually, the very first line of the [faq] explicitly says `Server Fault is for Information Technology Professionals needing expert answers related to managing computer systems in a professional capacity.` When you create an account, you are prompted to read the [faq] before asking or answering, and this is the reason. This site specifically targets professionals with questions about professional environments, specifically so that we can attract experts in the field.

Comment: @Andre - Calm down a bit. From a computer that is already joined to the domain look at the DNS servers configured in the TCP/IP properties of the NIC and echo those settings on the Windows 7 computer that you're trying to join to the domain and then try to join the domain again.